# Leaflet how to filter markers

Tags: leaflet

so I'm gonna show two things,
1) [This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAehw.png)

2) This is my code:
This is my code:

```
// center of the map
var center = [14.240861626831018, 121.12966240455648];
var osmUrl = 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        osm = L.tileLayer(osmUrl, 
            { 
                maxZoom: 17,
                minZoom:13
            }),
        map = new L.Map('map', 
            {
                attributionControl: false,
                center: new L.LatLng(14.240861626831018, 121.12966240455648), zoom: 13 
            }),
        drawnItems = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
L.control.layers({
    'osm': osm.addTo(map),
    "google": L.tileLayer('http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', 
    {
        attribution: 'google',
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom:13
    }),
    "monolight": L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', 
    {
        attribution: 'google',
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom:13,
        id: 'mapbox.light'
    }),
    "dark": L.tileLayer('https://cartodb-basemaps-{s}.global.ssl.fastly.net/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', 
    {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> &copy; <a href="http://cartodb.com/attributions">CartoDB</a>',
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        maxZoom: 20,
        minZoom:13
    })
}, { 'Enable markers': drawnItems }, 
    { 
        position: 'bottomleft', 
        collapsed: true 
    }).addTo(map);

map.addControl(new L.Control.Draw({
            position: 'bottomleft',
            edit: {
                edit:false,
                remove: true,
                featureGroup: drawnItems,
                poly: {
                    allowIntersection: false
                }
            },
            draw: {
                polygon: {
                    allowIntersection: false,
                    showArea: true
                },
            // disable toolbar item by setting it to false
            polygon: true, 
            polyline:true,
            circle: false,
            rectangle:false,
            marker: true,
            circlemarker: false
            }
        }));
map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
            var type = e.layerType,
                layer = e.layer;

            map.addLayer(layer);

                if (type === 'marker') {    
                    layer.bindPopup('LatLng: ' + layer.getLatLng()).openPopup();
                }
            });
```

I was wondering if separating the markers using checkbox is possible?
I mean I want to make separate checkboxes for each marker. Like if I only want to show the lines, I can hide the markers and polygons. Sorry for the mess. Thanks!

Comment: You're already using a LayerControl for the base layers, you can use it for overlay layers as well. If you direct each type of feature into its own layer you can switch the individual layers on and off with the LayerControl.

Comment: I'll try, thanks for the hint.

Comment: okay, I give up, can't figure out what you're saying..

Comment: OK, in outline: Create separate featureGroups for the different types of feature you want to switch. Add those to the map, don't add the 'drawnItems' featureGroup. Hook the 'draw:created' and 'draw:deleted' events, and maintain a copy of each feature in the appropriate featureGroup for the type of feature it is. Switch the featureGroups with the layerControl.

Comment: I tried to understand what you're saying but I have no clue at all, I'm sorry I just started using leaflet. but thanks for explaining though